# replies to support tickets

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm creating a support ticket system, and now i'm wondering about something, i can't figure out how to make reply system on each ticket. The problem is i don't know how to store replies and load them for each ticket. For example if ticket is like dashboard.php?id=3 to load me only replies from that ticked ID if it has questions in it and like that for other tickets, this is the code i have at the moment:

// this is loading of all user tickets

```
    if (!isset($_GET['action'])) 
    {
            echo "

            </br><div class='dashboard_info'>Dobrodosli, ovo je vas dashboard. Njegova svrha je pomaganje novim clanovima nase zajednice ali i starijima koji
            imaju poteskoce u snalazenju sa radom User Control Panela. Koriscenjem istog imate razne opcije, ali glavna svrha ovog dela jeste resavanje raznih problema otvaranjem tiketa i slanjem upita.
            Ispod mozete videti vase aktivne tikete ukoliko imate istih, ukoliko vam treba pomoc oko necega mozete poslati tiket klikom na Novi Tiket.</div>

            </br></br></br><center>
            <div class='dataTables'>

                <table>
                <tr>
                      <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>Naslov Tiketa</td>
                      <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>#ID Tiketa</td>
                      <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>Status Tiketa</td>
                      <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>Vrsta Tiketa</td>
                      <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>Datum</td>
                      </tr>

            </center>
";
            $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
            $author = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Dashboard WHERE Postavio = '$author'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
            {
                $ID = clear($row['ID']);
                $Naslov = clear($row['Naslov']);
                $Status = clear($row['Status']);
                $Vrsta = clear($row['Vrsta']);
                $Datum = clear($row['Datum']);

                if($Status == 0) { $statusinfo = "Otvoren"; }
                else if($Status == 1) { $statusinfo = "Zatvoren"; }
                else if($Status == 2) { $statusinfo = "Odgovoren"; }

                echo "

                  <tr CLASS='MYTABLE'>
                    <td CLASS='MYTABLE'><a href='dashboard.php?id=$ID'>$Naslov</a></td>
                    <td CLASS='MYTABLE'><a href='dashboard.php?id=$ID'>#0000$ID</a></td>
                    <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>$statusinfo</td>
                    <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>$Vrsta</td>
                    <td CLASS='MYTABLE'>$Datum</td>
                  <tr>

                  ";    
              }
      }
```

// this is loading of page with id

```
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
        $id = clear($_GET['id']); 
        $user =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['username']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `dashboard` WHERE `Postavio` = '$username' AND `ID` = '$id'";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $output = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($output == 0)
        {
            echo "Vi ste vlasnik ovog ticketa";
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Vi niste vlasnik ovog ticketa";
        }
  }
```

but this doesnt work well even, it should get id from url and compare it to one in database and see if it's made by the user, and if its made by someone else than it should return him to main page.

Comment: When you say that doesn't work well. You should really be more explicit if you want real help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...it should get id from url and compare it to one in database and see if it's made by the user, and if its made by someone else than it should return him to main page.

Look at these statements here,

```
$id = clear($_GET['id']); 
$user =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['username']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `dashboard` WHERE `Postavio` = '$username' AND `ID` = '$id'";
                                                            ^ it should be $user
 mysqli_query($con, $query);
^ You're not storing the result set.
```

First store the result set in a variable, and then use `mysqli_num_rows()` function.

So your code should be like this:

```
// your code

$query = "SELECT * FROM `dashboard` WHERE `Postavio` = '$user' AND `ID` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$output = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($output){    
    // You are the owner of this ticket
    echo "Vi ste vlasnik ovog ticketa";
}else{
    // redirect the user to main page
    header("Location: mainpage.php");
    exit();
}

// your code
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured that out, but im still wondering about comment system

Comment: @Nathaniel Once you found that the user is the owner of the ticket, you can display his/her details inside `if($output){ ... }` block. What else you're trying to do?

Comment: I know that, but i dont know how to store comments for each ticket, For example if i create ticket and ticket id is 10 i reply on that ticket, and then that reply should store insite database, but only for that ticket id, when i open ticket with id 120 i dont want other comments loaded

Comment: @Nathaniel You can create a separate table with the following fields `<comment_id, ticket_id, user, content>`. And while formulating the query inside `if($output){ ... }` block you can do like this: `SELECT content FROM comment_table WHERE ticket_id='$id' AND Postavio = '$user'`. Hopefully this will give some idea how to proceed further.

Comment: thank you i will try and do that :)